# How do I use IntBinaryOperator with a Switch Case Statement for Java Swing? (Simple Calculator)

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm having trouble getting an output while using the switch-statement and IntBinaryOperator. I'm trying to build a simple calculator in Java, and I found that the IntBinaryOperator cut down on unnecessary boilerplate code. I hope that you can show me the best approach. Thank you.

The three classes that I wrote are below.

```
package gui_calc;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator;

public class CalculatorJFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    static protected JLabel lblOut;
    private JButton btnEq;
    private JButton btnClear;

    public CalculatorJFrame() {
        setTitle("CALCULATOR");
        JPanel container = new JPanel(); //create a JPanel inside the JFrame as a container
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //add your components in here
        lblOut = new JLabel("");
        btnEq = new JButton("=");
        btnClear = new JButton("C");
        btnEq.addActionListener(this);
        btnClear.addActionListener(this);
        NumButtonsJP numBtns = new NumButtonsJP(); //create an instance of NumButtonsJP
        OpButtonsJP opBtns = new OpButtonsJP(); //create an instance of OpButtonsJP


        container.add(btnClear, BorderLayout.WEST);
        container.add(btnEq, BorderLayout.EAST);
        container.add(lblOut, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        container.add(numBtns, BorderLayout.CENTER); //add the numBtns JPanel to the container
        container.add(opBtns, BorderLayout.SOUTH); //add the opBtns JPanel to the container
        add(container); //add container to the JFrame
    }

    static protected void updateOutLabel(String suffix) {
        String currLblContent = lblOut.getText().trim(); //get current content of lblOut
        lblOut.setText(currLblContent + suffix); //update the output label on the main container
    }

    static protected void clearOutLabel() {
        lblOut.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String face = e.getActionCommand().trim();

        switch (face) {
            case "=":
                //do math... get the values... and reset the label with the result
                updateOutLabel("=" + getResultFromQuestion(lblOut.getText()));
                break;
            case "+":
                IntBinaryOperator add = (a,b) -> a + b;

                System.out.println("Your answer is" + (add));
                break;
            case "-":
                IntBinaryOperator substract = (a, b) -> a - b;
                System.out.println("Your answer is" + (substract.applyAsInt(lblOut.getText().charAt(0),lblOut.getText().charAt(1))));
                break;
            case "*":
                IntBinaryOperator multiply = (a, b) -> a * b;
                System.out.println("Your answer is" + (multiply));
                break;
            case "/":
                IntBinaryOperator divide = (a, b) -> a / b;
                System.out.println("Your answer is" + divide);
            case "C":
                clearOutLabel();
                break;
        }

    }

    private String getResultFromQuestion(String text) {
        double resultStr = 10;

        return "" + resultStr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create instance of calculator and run it
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                CalculatorJFrame calcGUI = new CalculatorJFrame();
                calcGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(calcGUI.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                calcGUI.setSize(300, 300);
                calcGUI.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }




  package gui_calc;

    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class OpButtonsJP extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("+");
        JButton btnSub = new JButton("-");
        JButton btnMul = new JButton("*");
        JButton btnDiv = new JButton("/");
        JButton [] opsBtns = {btnAdd, btnSub, btnMul, btnDiv};//array of jbuttons

        public OpButtonsJP(){
            setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));
            for(int i=0; i<opsBtns.length; i++){
                add(opsBtns[i]); //add the button to the JPanel
                opsBtns[i].addActionListener(this); //add the ActionListener to make the button functional
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String face = e.getActionCommand();
            System.out.println(face + " was clicked");
            CalculatorJFrame.updateOutLabel(face);
            //String currLblContent = CalculatorJFrame.lblOut.getText();
            //CalculatorJFrame.lblOut.setText(currLblContent + face); //update the output label on the main container
        }

    }

package gui_calc;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class NumButtonsJP extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    JButton numButtons[];

    public NumButtonsJP() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));
        numButtons = new JButton[10];
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            //create a JButton with the number on its face and add it to the array of JButtons
            numButtons[i] = new JButton("" + i);
            numButtons[i].addActionListener(this); //make the button trigger the event
            //add the JButton to the JPanel
            add(numButtons[i]);
        }
        JLabel spaceHolder = new JLabel(); //create the spaceHolder as a blank label
        add(spaceHolder); //add the spaceHolder to the JPanel
        numButtons[0] = new JButton("0"); //create the Zero button
        numButtons[0].addActionListener(this);//make the Zero button trigger actioNPerformed
        add(numButtons[0]); //add the Zero button to the JPanel
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String face = e.getActionCommand();
        System.out.println(face + " was clicked");
        int num = Integer.parseInt(face.trim()); // parse to an int so we can use in math
        CalculatorJFrame.updateOutLabel(face);
        //String currLblContent = CalculatorJFrame.lblOut.getText();
        //CalculatorJFrame.lblOut.setText(currLblContent + face); //update the output label on the main container

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand what the problem is exactly. The OpButtonsJP is using itself as ActionListener, not the CalculatorJFrame, so that should explain why they never use the switch statement. What was the question again?

Answer (score 1):

I change a little your code, basically I'm adding an evaluator of expressions.
The UI basically construct the expression and pass to your getResultFromQuestion() function which takes the input and then try to parse to a math function. 
You must handle the exceptions properly, and it brokes your BinaryOperators since you could entry two of more operands.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String face = e.getActionCommand().trim();
    switch (face) {
    case "=":
        // do math... get the values... and reset the label with the result
        updateOutLabel("=" + getResultFromQuestion(lblOut.getText()));
        break;
    case "C":
        clearOutLabel();
        break;
    }
}
private String getResultFromQuestion(String text) {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
    Object result = null;
    try {
        result = engine.eval(text);
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        //Do something with the exception
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting approach. It works really well. Thank you.